# What can be done about a milky residue left on engineered flooring after cleaning?

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, stain-removal

My wife and I are having major renovations done in our house by a local builder and although he has done a fantastic job with everything up to now, we are not happy with the engineered flooring that they have laid.

It seems to be covered in this milky/chalky finish except for the edges near to the skirting. We called the builder around and he has told us that they were supplied cleaner and oil from the flooring manufacturer and this is the finish that the oil gives. He says that it will wear down/disappear over time.

Believe me, I am no expert with flooring, but I can see that something is not right. It looks terrible...he has said that he could clean the oil off but it would darken the shade of the floor.

Recommendations?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE. While "any advice" questions are generally off-topic here, you could edit to ask something more specific. Questions about dealing with your builder are also off-topic, though.

Comment: Also, please edit to explain whether the flooring was raw or pre-finished, and what your expectations were.

Comment: This is why I'm not a fan of this 'oil finish' or whatever it's called. Wood needs to be sealed properly. If you want it to look like a barn, well then, it's going to look like a barn ;)

Answer (score 1):

Oh my. That is terrible. I'm assuming the floor was really unfinished. I'd confirm that because putting harsh cleaners on a finished piece can look like that. I've personally never seen a oil/wax finish look that bad before buffing but I'd say it at least needs to be buffed. More concerning is why they wouldn't oil/wax every inch. It stops well shy of the base boards. If it was unfinished,  every inch needs to be finished or will always look multi colored. The more I think about it, the more I would spend the money to have someone come out that specializes in wood flooring to evaluate it. I don't think your guy has much experience with wood flooring.